# How to set a background of a radio button programmatically from the default resources

Tags: android

I want to set a radio button background programmatically  using java

```
 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
```

I used this code , but it did not work

```
 awgg.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

awgg.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_dropdown_light_frame);

this the answer